# Can't infer type in generic tostring method C#

Tags: c#, types, type-inference

I have a custom facilitator method that takes a value, and determines its type. If it's a data structure such that it can be enumerated over, then it gets passed to its respective `ToString` method to be printed out. But if not, then it's builtin `.ToString()` method is called.

```
public static String GetString<T> (T value)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if (t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(IDictionary)))
        return _GetString_Dictionary(value);
    else if (t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(IEnumerable)))
        return _GetString_Enumerable (value);
    else
        return value.ToString ();
}
```

However, I'm getting lots of errors related to how the argument types can't be inferred for each call to the other methods. I currently have no initiative as to how to solve this problem; can it even be accomplished?

Here are the other toString methods that the above one calls, for reference;

```
private static String _GetString_Dictionary<KT, VT> (Dictionary<KT, VT> d)
{
    string s = "{";
    foreach (var pair in d)
        s += GetString(pair.Key) + " : " + GetString(pair.Value) + ", ";
    return s.Substring (0, s.Length - 2) + "}";
}

private static String _GetString_Enumerable<T> (IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    string s = "[";
    foreach (T i in e)
        s += GetString(i) + ", ";
    return s.Substring(0, s.Length-2) + "]";
}
```

Edit: Shortened code as per Equiso's Information.

---

As per David Manning's example, I've modified the code to look as such;

```
public static String GetString<KT, VT> (Dictionary<KT, VT> d)
{
    string s = "{";
    foreach (var pair in d)
        s += GetString(pair.Key) + " : " + GetString(pair.Value) + ", ";
    return s.Substring (0, s.Length - 2) + "}";
}

public static String GetString<T> (IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    string s = "[";
    foreach (T i in e)
        s += GetString(i) + ", ";
    return s.Substring(0, s.Length-2) + "]";
}

public static String GetString<T> (T value)
{
    return value.ToString ();
}
```

It no longer throws errors.

Edit: It does not work as intended; it instead calls the generic `.ToString()` version of `GetString()` on every object passed to it, instead of it's more specific overload if it were otherwise applicable. Passing a `List` object to it returns the string `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`. instead of the contents of the list.

Comment: This isn't what you asked but, rather than all the `if` statements in your `GetString()` method, doesn't it make more sense to just create a `MyToString()` method overloaded with more specialized argument. C# will automatically pick the most appropriate one if it's done correctly.

Comment: How would this be done? I'm not familiar with this usage of C#.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry missed the requirement for the recursive application of your GetString method, I have updated my answer to support this. Looks a lot more like your original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use generics here, you can define `GetString` with the non-generic collection interfaces and the compiler will bind your calls to the most specific one. For example:

```
public static String GetString(object value) {

    if (value is string) {
        return value as string;
    } else if (value is IDictionary) {
        return GetString(value as IDictionary);
    } else if (value is IEnumerable) {
        return GetString(value as IEnumerable);
    } else {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}

public static String GetString(string l) {
    return l;
}

public static String GetString(IEnumerable l) {
    string s = "[";
    foreach (object i in l) {
        s += GetString(i) + ", ";
    }
    if (s != "[") s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
    return s + "]";
}

public static String GetString(IDictionary d) {
    string s = "{";
    foreach (object key in d.Keys) {
        s += GetString(key) + " : " + GetString(d[key]) + ", ";
    }
    if (s != "{") s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
    return s + "}";
}
```

The Array, List and `IEnumerable<T>` cases will all be covered by the `IEnumerable` overload. Note: overload for string required as we don't want to treat it as `IEnumerable<Char>`.

Comment: Although I still ended up using generics (as it makes the purpose of the code easier to understand), I went with your method of creating multiple overloads for a single GetString function and letting the compiler handle the order, instead of trying to force the order and overload it myself using multiple other private functions. The code no longer throws errors, and works as intended. I might as well mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I didn't know you could use the `is` keyword in that manner. interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for your solution (Cast the value to its type):

```
public static String GetString<T> (T value)
{
  Type t = typeof(T);
  if (t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(Array)) || t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(IList)))
    return _ToString_List ((List)value);
  else if (t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(IDictionary)))
    return _ToString_Dictionary((Dictionary)value);
  else if (t.IsSubclassOf (typeof(IEnumerable)))
    return _ToString_Enumerable ((IEnumerable)value);
  else
    return value.ToString ();
}
```

A more elegant solution will be using extension method

```
public static class ToStringExtension()
{
  publicstatic String MyToString<T> (this T[] a) 
  {
  if (a.Length == 0)
    return "[]";
  string s = "[";
  for (int i=0; i<a.Length - 1; i++)
    s += GetString(a [i]) + ", ";
  return s + a [a.Length - 1] + "]";
  }

  public static String MyToString<KT, VT> (this Dictionary<KT, VT> d)
  {
  string s = "{";
  foreach (var pair in d)
    s += GetString(pair.Key) + " : " + GetString(pair.Value) + ", ";
  return s.Substring (0, s.Length - 2) + "}";
  }

  public static String MyToString<T> (this IEnumerable<T> e)
  {
  string s = "[";
  foreach (T i in e)
    s += GetString(i) + ", ";
  return s.Substring(0, s.Length-2) + "]";
  }
}
```

To use the extension method:

```
var arr = new string[10];
arr.MyToString();
```

Comment: Your quick fix didn't work. And regarding your other solution, I would prefer a single method that I can call with any data structure to print out it's contents recursively, as my above methods ought to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you are trying to generate json you can save yourself a lot of pain by just using a library like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), serializing objects is not as simple as you would think.

---

You can create methods with the same name but different parameters and when you run the code C# will choose the right one to execute depending on the type you pass as an argument, you don't need to test the type of it.

You only need two overloads, one for `IEnumerables` which covers `Lists` and `Arrays` too, and one for `Dictionary`.

Also you can use some framework methods to join the strings `string.Join` which will add the separator only between elements, so you don't have to worry about removing trailing commas.

Here's a small working example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Experiments {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var array = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
            var list = new List<string> { "four", "five", "six" };
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"k1", "v1"},
                {"k2", "v2"},
                {"k3", "v2"},
            };

            Console.WriteLine(GetString(array));
            Console.WriteLine(GetString(list));
            Console.WriteLine(GetString(dictionary));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string GetString<T>(IEnumerable<T> value) {
            return "["
                + string.Join(", ", value)
                + "]";
        }

        public static string GetString<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> value) {
            return "{"
                + string.Join(", ", value.Select(entry => entry.Key + " : " + entry.Value))
                + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what about unordered data structures, like sets? does `IEnumerable` cover those too?

Comment: @Maurdekye What class exactly are you thinking of? If you are talking about a class from the .net framework that you can iterate it will implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: If you are thinking of some class that implements the `ISet<T>` interface then yes, `ISet` also implements `IEnumerable`, it doesn't matter that it is an unordered structure, the `IEnumerable` interface guarantees that you can go over each element, it doesn't make any promise about the order in which you'll get the items though.

Comment: But if I use a foreach loop on a List, will it give me the items in order?

Comment: Yes, Lists, Collections and Arrays guarantee the order, all are backed up by arrays.  Most of the time you can expect the same order unless the documentation for the class explicitly states it doesn't.

Comment: Nonetheless, this code won't work for lists within lists in the same way mine does. However, I did shorten my given code to remove the `_ToString_List` methods as they were unnecessary.